# Assigning multiple variables from a list in a for loop in Python

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, twitter

I want to dynamically assign a variable depending on what value I am currently iterating over in a list. I'm trying to figure out how to do this and am currently trying to use exec(). The aim is to automatically iterate of tweets from different twitter lists and store them in separate collections named after the name of the twitter list, I leave some of that code in for further context of the flow.

```
slug_list = ["slug1","slug2","slug3"]

for slug in slug_list:
        exec("current_collection = db.{}".format(slug))

        tweets = api.list_timeline("@username",slug)
        for tweet in tweets_cursor:
            current_collection.insert(tweet)
```

This creates the following error:

```
NameError: name 'current_collection' is not defined
```

How could I solve this, and preferably learn why this happens?

Comment: Instead of using "dynamic assignment", just use the Python builtin method `getattr`. For example: `current_collection = getattr(db, slug)`.

Comment: Well, that solves the problem and I guess I can read up on getattr() in the docs to understand why that is a better approach. :-)

Comment: to put it simply, `getattr` just calls the magic method of the object `__getattr__`. This means that `getattr(db, slug)` is almost exactly the same as `db.slug`.

Answer (score 0):

Use gettattr() instead as suggested by commenter